# Overrriding spring version in Spring boot/ spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I note that with spring cloud Angel.SR3 which uses Spring Boot 1.2.4, the spring version loaded is 4.1.6.RELEASE.

There is a memory leak issue in the yaml processor that I read was fixed in spring 4.1.7.RELEASE.

Specifically addressed in this https://jira.spring.io/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=14936 ([SPR-13173] - YAML Processor leaves StreamDecoder open)

I tracked through and saw that the starters use ${spring.version} to specify the spring version to be used.

I tried overriding by adding 4.1.7.RELEASE to my properties, but it still loads the 4.1.6 version

Anyway I can do this?  I understand that these are curated but this particular memory leak is causing us a lot of issues.

As requested I have attached the front part of the pom.  All base dependencies are pulled in through the spring cloud parent.  I noticed that they use ${spring.version} to define the correct value of spring.  I attempted to override it via a property setting.  At no time in the rest of the my pom do I explicitly bring in any of the spring framework libs.  The parent pom does that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.libertas.vipaas</groupId>
    <artifactId>vipaas-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Vipaas Starter</name>
    <description>Vipaas Starter</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Angel.SR3</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
         ..... other stuff ...

    </properties>
    ... other stuff as not relevant ....
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Maven, correct? Please share you pom as the answer depends on how you're using the dependency management from Spring Cloud and Spring Boot.

Comment: I can see that Spring boot 1.2.5 uses spring 4.1.7.RELEASE.  I guess this is more a question of when 1.2.5 will be the basis for spring cloud.  Currently the latest release is at spring boot 1.2.4

Comment: Still a valid question. I wanted to bump Spring Boot to 1.3.1.RELEASE, but getting some mixed springframework dependencies (4.2.3 + 4.2.4)  from Spring Cloud (Brixton.M3). I would like to have them all at the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Using *dependencyManagement* it should work:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

You can check it with:

```
mvn help:effective-pom | grep -A1 "artifactId>spring-context"
```